# とは言え conjunction

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I often hear とは言え used as a conjunction between sentences. What does it mean?

ALC didn't offer much help.

Comment: I don't know about that ALC thing, but you should give jisho.org a try when you cannot find the words you are looking for.

Comment: Typically written in kana (but kanji is not incorrect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's on ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%88&ref=sa). It's listed in hiragana because it's a fossilized conjunction.

- とはいえ: nevertheless; that being said; be it as it may

Etymologically, this is 'quotative-と' + 'thematic-は' + '已然形 of 言う（言ふ）'. Hence literally "that being said."

Comment: Ah, silly me, I was search with the kanji and it wasn't coming up. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically used as "but".

Literally it means something like "it can be said".

For example,

> 偶然の出会いだった。とは言え、必然という運命を感じる。
>   Although it can be said that I met her by coincidence, it felt like destiny to me.