# What does this あれ mean?

Tags: grammar

In a manga there is a stern elf that is reprimanding his fellow adventurer for making fun of someone over drinks:

「その少年に謝罪することはあれ
　酒の肴にする権利などない」

Note that there is a line break between the two halves, so it's unclear if it's two sentences or one. I'm very confused on how this あれ functions grammatically. It sounds like a conjugation of 有る, but not like the imperative form (e.g. フォースと共にあれ). Is this some other grammatical form that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This あれ is the 已然形 of the verb ある, and means あっても, "even though there is..."

> その少年に謝罪することはあれ 　酒の肴にする権利などない  ← sounds literary
> ≈ その少年に謝罪することは**あっても** 　酒の肴にする権利などない

Similar examples:

> - 理由は何で**あれ**、盗みはいけない。
>   ≈理由は何で**あっても**、～～～
> - 9月とは**言え**、まだ残暑が続いております。
>   ≈9月とは**言っても**、～～～

Related threads:

- [とは言え conjunction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44991/9831)
- [What exactly does とはいえ mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3949/9831)

Comment: This use of the 已然形【いぜんけい】 or "realis form" is somewhat similar to the use of the subjunctive in English: presenting a hypothetical as an introduction to a contrary statement that goes against that hypothetical.  Compare the phrase _"**be** that as it may, ..."_, or more specific to the sample sentence, _"even **should** he **be** guilty,..."_ where the _"be"_ and _"should be"_ align with the あれ in the sample sentence.

Comment: Maybe worth to say that 已然形 is no longer a part of the living grammar, only fossilized in some constructions like this.

Comment: I wonder if this usage of 已然形 is derived from shortening of 已然形+ど. For example, とはいえど -> とはいえ, 何であれど -> 何であれ, etc. Not sure how it applies to にしろ or にせよ.

Comment: @JimmyYang, しろ and せよ are imperative conjugations, not realis.

Answer (score 0):

means acceptable/ doable in contrast of the second sentence that is unacceptable/ not doable

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for a more thorough explanation of the grammar involved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: あれ is the short form of (あれば),a potential form of 有る（ある) . So the grammar using here is a pair of ～あれ、～ない ,  basically there will be two condition,  (first condition) あれ、(second condition)ない , means rather to do (first condition) than (second condition). Hope this help